Find smallest $n$ such that among any $n$ of the students' answer sheets, there exist $4$ of them among which any $2$ have at most $3$ common answers.
This is problem 9.107 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
An exam paper consists of five multiple-choice questions, each with four different choices; $2000$
students take the test, and each student chooses exactly one answer per question. Find the smallest value of $n$ for which it is possible for the students' answer sheets have the following property: among any $n$ of the students' answer sheets, there exist four of them among which any two have at most three common answers.
Here is my attempt.
Let $\{1,2,3,4\}$ be the $4$ different choices for each question. We record the students' answers with $2000\times5$ matrices, where each row represents a student and the $j^{th}$ column represents the answers of the students to the $j^{th}$ question. If $n$ is a value for which the property in question is satisfied, then there exists a $2000\times5$ matrix $M$ in which each entry is either $1,2,3$ or $4$ such that among any $n$ rows, there exist $4$ of them among which the hamming distance between any $2$ rows is at least $2$.
I don't know how to find the smallest value of $n$ or prove that it is indeed the smallest value.
The lowest bound that I currently have is $n=751$.
Define a matrix $M$ by the following:
We first define the entries for the first $3$ columns. For the first $500$ entries, let each entry be $1$. For the next $500$ entries, let each entry be $2$. Similarly, $3$ for the next $500$ and $4$ for the last $500$.
We now define the entries the last $2$ columns.
Let the first $250$ entries of the $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ columns be $1$ and $3$ respectively. Let the next $250$ entries of the $4^{th}$ and $5^{th}$ columns be $2$ and $4$ respectively. We define the next $500$ rows in exactly the same row. Same goes for the next $500$ and the last $500$.
Divide the matrix into $8$ blocks of $250$ rows in which each row has the same entry. Note that any $2$ rows in different blocks have a hamming distance of at least $2$ between them.
If we pick any $751$ of the rows, then at least $4$ of them must each belong to a different block. So $n=751$ satisfies the property for this particular matrix.

A $2000 \times 5$ matrix will hold all the answers of all the students.  You are trying to select $n$ columns that have the required property.  The question is flawed as it may not be possible to select the desired papers.  Imagine if all the students gave exactly the same answers.

I don't understand what the "any $4$ of the $n$" adds to the problem.  I believe what it is trying to ask is the maximum number of papers such that each is at least a Hamming distance of $2$ from all the others.

@RossMillikan Let me clarify "any $4$ of the $n$". What it means is that if we were to pick any $n$ of the $2000$ students' answer sheets, we can find $4$ of those $n$ answer sheets such that any $2$ of those $4$ answer sheets have at most $3$ common answers.
It is possible that that all the students gave exactly the same answers. In this case, the matrix holding the answers does not satisfy the property. But the problem is asking for the minimum $n$ such that a matrix satisfying the required property exist.

But increasing $n$ makes it harder, not easier.  If $n=5$ works, $n=4$ is guaranteed to because there are less possibilities that have to work.

Wait, shouldn't increasing $n$ makes it easier? I mean if $n=4$ works, then $n\ge 5$ works since any $n\ge 5$ answer sheets has $4$ answer sheets.

No.  If $n=4$ works it might be that adding one more test into the group results in a pair with too many common answers.  If $n=5$ works you are guaranteed to be able to remove any paper and still have it work, so $n=4$ will work.

Note there are only $4^5=1024$ possible sets of answers, so there will be many matching pairs.  If you pick two pairs of matching papers you fail so it can't even be any $4$.  That is why I say the question does not make sense as written.

Umm, it's not any $4$, it's any $n$.

I've edited the question for clarification.

You still have the problem that all the students might have answered the same, so all the rows are identical.

That is a possible scenario but that doesn't disprove that an integer $n$ required by the problem at hand exist since we could have other scenarios like the examples that I've given.

@RossMillikan I think I get what you mean now. If I understand correctly, in the case that if all the students have answered the same, all the rows are identical. So if we pick any 2 of the students answer sheets, they will clearly be matching pairs, and have all answers common. In this case the matrix recording the answer sheets doesn't have an $n$ such that the required property exist. Is that what you meant?

The question asks, "For which $n$ it is possible for the students' answer sheets have this property?" This means that we should feel free to choose the $2000$ answer sheets however we like, to try to make $n$ as small as possible. (Having all the students answer the same is a bad choice!)

@MishaLavrov Thanks for that. I thought I was being unclear.

We first show $n\gt24$.
For any $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\in\{1,2,3,4\}^4$, define the set $S_v=\{(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,k)^T|k\in\{1,2,3,4\}\}$. Let $A$ be an arbitrary $2000\times5$ matrix of which each entry belongs to $\{1,2,3,4\}$. By the pigeonhole principle, there are $\lceil \frac{2000}{256} \rceil=8$ rows, say the first $8$ rows, that belong to $S_a$ for some $a\in\{1,2,3,4\}^4$. Similarly, among the rest of the $1992$ rows, there are $\lceil \frac{1992}{256} \rceil=8$ rows, say the $9^{th}$ to $16^{th}$ rows, such that each row belongs to $S_b$ for some $b\in\{1,2,3,4\}^4$. Among the rest of the $1984$ rows, there are $\lceil \frac{1984}{256} \rceil=8$ rows, say the $17^{th}$ to $24^{th}$ rows, such that each row belongs to $S_c$ for some $c\in\{1,2,3,4\}^4$. Among the first $24$ rows of $A$, if we pick any $4$ of the rows, there must be $2$ rows that belong to the same $S_u$, where $u\in \{a,b,c\}$. So the hamming distance between those $2$ rows is at most $1$. It follows that $n\gt24$.
We now show $n=25$ works.
Define the set $S=\{(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)^T|v_j\in\{1,2,3,4\},\sum_j^{5}v_j\equiv0 \pmod4\}$. Note that the hamming distance between any $2$ distinct vectors in $S$ is at least $2$. Since $|S|=4^4=256$, we may pick $250$ vectors from $S$ and construct a $2000\times5$ matrix $M$ such that each of those $250$ vectors appears in exactly $8$ rows of $M$. If we pick any $25$ rows from $M$, then there exists $\lceil \frac{25}{8} \rceil =4$ rows that are pairwise distinct. It follows that $n=25$ works.
Therefore, $n=25$ is the required smallest value.
